# Raphael.js map How to add points or path image to path by obj.click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day,

I built an interactive map using Raphael.js. So now I want to add text with image note by clicking on path map.

At this time note download as png image, is it possible to change it for another path or points?

**The path.js**

```
var russia = {
        map3: {
            troizki: {
                name: 'Троицкий АО',
                image:  'M141.3,519.',
                path: 'M141.3,519.5 c4,0.1,6.7,1,5.2,6.2c-2.1,7.4-...
            }
```

**The init.js**

```
$(function(){

    var map = 'troizki';
    var r = Raphael(map, 700, 850),
        attributes = {
            fill: '#e6e7e8',
            stroke: '#B5B5B5',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        },
        arr = new Array();

    for (var country in russia[map]) {

        var obj4 = r.path(russia[map][country].path);
        obj4.attr(attributes);
        arr[obj4.id] = country; 

        obj4.click(function(){
          document.location.hash = arr[this.id];
          var point = this.getBBox(0);
          $('#'+map).next('.point').remove();
          $('#'+map).after($('<div />').addClass('point'));
          // **IMAGE HERE**
          $('.point')
          .html('<p>'+russia[map][arr[this.id]].name+'</p>')      
          .prepend($('<img />').attr('src', 'img/'+arr[this.id]+'.png'))
          .css({
          left: point.x+(point.width)+215,
          top: point.y+(point.height/2)+10
          })
          .fadeIn();
          }
            }); 
    }       
});
```